# pandas interpolate only when values exist on both sides

Tags: python, pandas

consider `pd.Series` `s`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([np.nan, 1, np.nan, 3, np.nan])
```

---

***How do I interpolate to get:***

```
pd.Series([np.nan, 1, 2, 3, np.nan])

0    NaN
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```

**note:** I want the first and last `np.nan` to remain

I only want to fill in values when I have values on both sides to do the the interpolation.

In other words, I want to interpolate, not extrapolate.

Comment: Here is a github discussion:  https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/10691#issuecomment-127036592

Comment: Kinda strange I guess, but limit_direction can be forward, backward, or both.  Would be nice to have "neither" as an option which would make the solution here trivial.  FWIW, syntax is a little strange IMO for this command due to attempts to preserve backwards compatibility with old syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do this - skipping the heading and tailing NAs:

```
s.iloc[s.first_valid_index():s.last_valid_index()+1].interpolate()
```

Comment: I'd use `ix` and skip the `+1`... `s.ix[s.first_valid_index():s.last_valid_index()].interpolate()`.  Then to produce my results, use `combine_first` or `update`... `s.combine_first(s.ix[s.first_valid_index():s.last_valid_index()].interpolate()) `

Comment: I'd use `loc` over `ix`, as you're getting back the actual index, and `ix` will be [deprecated soon](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14218).

Comment: You can indeed, I just try to avoid ix and not use it anymore as it has a mixed behavior, and the trend from the author and core developers of pandas is expressed as "let's remove ix from pandas"